# Package 'bridge-utils' has no installation candidate

Tags: 16.04, apt, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to install KVM in ubuntu 16.04 using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
```

and getting following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package bridge-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bridge-utils' has no installation candidate
```

Can anyone help me to install KVM in ubuntu OS?

Comment: Did you forget to run `sudo apt-get update`? The package `bridge-utils` is available for [all current releases](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=bridge-utils).

Comment: @DevHugo I have referred the link that you have shared. It was really helpful. I have installed KVM in Ubuntu. But got new problem now when I am executing the command:  
`sudo kvm-ok`

I am getting following error:

`INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist`
`HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel`
`INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions`
`INFO: KVM (vmx) is disabled by your BIOS`
`HINT: Enter your BIOS setup and enable Virtualization Technology (VT),
      and then hard poweroff/poweron your system`
`KVM acceleration can NOT be used`

Help me to fix the problem.

Comment: Hi @N0rbert ,
Now I could able to install bridge-utils. Please, read my new issue above. Help me to fix that.
Thank you.

Comment: @ShankarMuthusamy You need to go in your PC BIOS and "Security" section (If my memory is good) and enable the VT-X.